# Preventing URL string from being encoded in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm not very good at JavaScript and have some code that was written for me:

```
if (args[2].LocationCacheTypeID == 1) {
  locationInput.name = 'Cities';
```

I'd like to add `LinkID=27201&` to the code as seen below:

```
if (args[2].LocationCacheTypeID == 1) {
  locationInput.name = 'LinkID=272081&Cities';
```

The only problem is that when I add it and it's turned into a URL string the result is:

```
?LinkID%3D272081%26Cities=Poquoson
```

It turns the `=` to `%3D` and the `&` to `%26`.

How can I fix this?

The full original script is:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function() {
  var dataSource = new YAHOO.util.ScriptNodeDataSource('http://api.idx.diversesolutions.com/API/Locations/33266/81?');
  var ac = new YAHOO.widget.AutoComplete('vrcsf_location', 'vrcsf_location_ac', dataSource);

  dataSource.responseSchema = {
    resultsList: '',
    fields: ['LocationName','LocationCacheTypeID','TotalCount']
  };

  ac.animVert = false;
  ac.queryMatchContains = true;
  ac.queryQuestionMark = false;
  ac.useShadow = true;
  ac.queryDelay = .1;
  ac.typeAhead = false;
  ac.allowBrowserAutocomplete = false;
  ac.alwaysShowContainer = false;
  ac.resultTypeList = false;
  ac.maxResultsDisplayed = 5;
  ac.resultTypeList = false;

  ac.generateRequest = function(query) {
    return 'partialName=' + query + '&maxAreasToReturn=5';
  };

  ac.formatResult = function(resultData, query, resultMatch) {
    var type;

    if (resultData.LocationCacheTypeID == 1) {
      type = 'City';
    } else if (resultData.LocationCacheTypeID == 2) {
      type = 'Community';
    } else if (resultData.LocationCacheTypeID == 3) {
      type = 'Tract';
    } else if (resultData.LocationCacheTypeID == 4) {
      type = 'Zip';
    } else if (resultData.LocationCacheTypeID == 5) {
      type = 'County';
    }
    return (resultMatch + ' (' +  type + ')');
  };

  ac.itemSelectEvent.subscribe(function(e, args) {
    var locationInput = YAHOO.util.Dom.get('vrcsf_location');

    if (args[2].LocationCacheTypeID == 1) {
      locationInput.name = 'Cities';
    } else if (args[2].LocationCacheTypeID == 2) {
      locationInput.name = 'Communities';
    } else if (args[2].LocationCacheTypeID == 3) {
      locationInput.name = 'Tracts';
    } else if (args[2].LocationCacheTypeID == 4) {
      locationInput.name = 'ZipCodes';
    } else if (args[2].LocationCacheTypeID == 5) {
      locationInput.name = 'Counties';
    }
  });
})();
```

Comment: Post the rest of the code. Your URL is being encoded.

Comment: Don't you use `encodeURIComponent`?

Comment: Added the full original script.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you trying to *add* a new GET key/value (`LinkID=272081`) to the URL, or *specifically* to the `locationInput.name` property? If it's the former, you can't do that, as whatever is calculating your URL from the `locationInput` object is encoding it. You need to add it at the property level, ie, `locationInput.linkid = '272081'`. And then check and edit it where it calculates the URL from `locationInput`.

Comment: Oh, okay.  So, it sounds like I won't be able to add it as is... because I'm limited to what I can do.

Comment: Do you need that appended to `http://api.idx.diversesolutions.com/API/Locations/33266/81`? If that's where it needs to be, you could try `http://api.idx.diversesolutions.com/API/Locations/33266/81?LinkID=272081` on the `dataSource` line and see if that works.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it didn't work.  I think the diversesolutions code and api are encoding it.  In which case I won't be able to fix it.  Thanks for your help though.